# How to nest comment and theorem in one environment?

Tags: environments, theorems, comments, nesting

I'm using `comment` and `amsthm` packages for comments and theorems.
I'd like to skip some theorems.
I've tried to create a new environment with theorem nested in a comment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,comment}
\excludecomment{myblock}

\newtheorem{thDef}{Definition}
\newenvironment{envDef}%
{\begin{myblock}\begin{thDef}}%
{\end{thDef}\end{myblock}}

\begin{document}
\begin{envDef}My definition.\end{envDef}
\end{document}
```

But I've got an error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

Did I miss something?

UPDATE: When I comment out the theorem environment directly, then LaTeX emits exactly the same error:

```
\newtheorem{thDef}{Definition}
\excludecomment{thDef}

! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide an environment marked with `\excludecomment` inside another environment's definition. The and `\end{myblock}` tag *must* appear explicitly in the input, because it's taken as a literal delimiter.

The solution is simpler:

```
% \excludecomments{envDef} % uncomment for not showing `envDef`

\newtheorem{thDef}{Definition}
\newenvironment{envDef}
  {\begin{thDef}}
  {\end{thDef}}
```